# Prove that $\mathscr B$ is satisfiable if and only if $(\exists y_1)...(\exists y_n)\mathscr B$ is satisfiable.

Tags: logic, solution-verification, first-order-logic

Prove that $\mathscr B$ is satisfiable if and only if $(\exists y_1)...(\exists y_n)\mathscr B$ is satisfiable. 
This question is from "Introduction to Mathmatical Logic" by Elliot Mendelson , forth edition , exercise 2.20.

The question is as follows:

> Prove that if the free variables of $\mathscr B$ are $y_1,...,y_n$ , then $\mathscr B$ is satisfiable if and only if $(\exists y_1)...(\exists y_n)\mathscr B$ is satisfiable.

**My attempt:**

I first start by proving a lemma

> lemma: $\mathscr B$ is satisfiable if and only if $(\exists x_i)\mathscr B$ is satisfiable.

proof: [$\to$]

1. If $\mathscr B$ is satisfiable , then there is a sequence $s$ in an interpretation $M$ such that $s$ satisfies $\mathscr B$.
2. $s$ doesn't satisfy $\lnot \mathscr B$
3. $s$ doesn't satisfy $(\forall x_i) \lnot \mathscr B$
4. $s$ satisfies $\lnot (\forall x_i) \lnot \mathscr B$
5. $s$ satisfies $(\exists x_i)\mathscr B$
6. $(\exists x_i)\mathscr B$ is satisfiable.

[$\leftarrow$]

1. $(\exists x_i)\mathscr B$ is satisfiable.
2. $\lnot (\forall x_i) \lnot \mathscr B$ is satisfiable
3. if $\lnot (\forall x_i) \lnot \mathscr B$ is satisfiable , then there is a $s$ in an interpretation $M$ such that $s$ satisfies $\lnot (\forall x_i) \lnot \mathscr B$.
4. $s$ doesn't satisfy $(\forall x_i) \lnot \mathscr B$.
5. There exists a sequence $s'$ that differs from $s$ atmost the $i_{th}$ element such that $s'$ doesn't satisfy $\lnot \mathscr B$
6. $s'$ satisfies $\mathscr B$

Thus the lemma is proven.

Now , to prove the main theorem , I will use induction.

1. $\mathscr B$ is satisfiable if and only if $(\exists y_n)\mathscr B$ is satisfiable.
2. $\mathscr B$ is satisfiable if and only if $(\exists y_m)\mathscr B$ is satisfiable. [where $1 \leq m<n$]

With this , the main theorem is proven. [end]

Now , I have some skepticism about my proof , for the reason that I didn't use a single time in my proof the information that:

> The free variables of $\mathscr B$ are $y_1,...,y_n$.

So I think there is a big flaw with my proof which I am simply ignoring and not able to find.Can someone tell me what is that flaw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no flaw in your proof. The requirement in the problem that the free variables of $\mathscr{B}$ are $y_1, \ldots, y_n$ is not necessary as the statement is true for any $y_1, \ldots, y_n$, which may include variables that do not occur free in $\mathscr{B}$ and need not includes all the free variables of $\mathscr{B}$: if $y$ is not free in $\mathscr{B}$, then $\mathscr{B}$ and $(\exists y)\mathscr{B}$ are logically equivalent and hence equisatisfiable; if $y$ and $z$ both occur free in $B$, then $(\exists y)(\exists z)\mathscr{B}$ and $(\exists z)\mathscr{B}$ are equisatisfiable. Your proof deals correctly with both of these cases.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Also , 1.Is my proof of the lemma "$\mathscr B$ is satisfiable if and only if $(∃x_i) \mathscr B$ is satisfiable." correct ? 2.What was the point of adding the extra unnecessary condition?

Comment: 1) Your proof is fine. 2) I don't know.Possibly an oversight.